# How to get current slider values from JQuery Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery slider , i want to all sliders current values when one slider is changing

**Slider code:**

```
var slider = jQuery("<div class='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select)
        .slider({
            min : 0,
            max : 4,
            range : "min",
            value : select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
            slide : function(event, ui) {


            },
            change: function(event, ui) { 


            }
        });
```

**I tried this:**

```
        change: function(event, ui) { 

            jQuery(".minbeds").each(function(){
                alert(jQuery(this).val());
            });          
        }
```

but whatever the slider values, it is only alerting the value `1`.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
   jQuery(".slider").slider("value");
```

will give the current slider value when change , but how can i get all slider values .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following line to access the current values of the slider:

```
var val = $('#slider').slider("option", "value");
```

Comment: that returns a complex object , and i already tried that one :( . is there an easy way

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: No,it returns integer value not complex object.

Comment: @YogeshWaran , yes sorry i used a wrong class . now it is working , thanks guys

Comment: I am getting "Null No properties" using this syntax in my chrome debugger, why is datfor jquerymobile @Zenith